# Can you share parent resource between terraform sub directories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform

I'm thinking about breaking up an application into micro-services using this terraform directory structure:

```
/staging
  /global
  /service1
  /service2
/prod
  /global
  /service1
  /service2
```

Suppose I would like each microservice to have it's own AWS Apigateway endpoint:

```
myurl.com/service1
myurl.com/service2
```

Both services can be part of the same parent AWS apigateway resource:

```
#creates the api (a parent of all resources), 
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name        = "API root parent"
  description = "Contains all endpoints"
}
```

My understanding is that each top level AWS REST api would be it's own cloudfront so I only need ONE of them for all my microservices instead of one REST api per microservice.  I would like to put the REST api declaration in the `/global` folder since that would be shared by all microservices.

Then in service1 subdirectory I would start defining resources that would need to reference the parent:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "service1" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "service1"
}
```

But how would the service1 subdirectory have access to the `api` resource since it's not defined in the same directory?

I might be able to import the state of an existing resource into the subdirectory, for each microservice subdirectory but that seems like a mess.

UPDATE: It looks like AWS api gateway only charges for usage so I can just create separate rest api resources for each subdirectory after all.  But I might still need to know how to collect the resource variables across the sub-folders in order to add the respective api deployment stages to a common custom domain.  Is there a technique or pattern for being able to separate projects mostly by folders but being able to extract variables and glue them together in `/global` which is not specific to each subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remote states** in terraform is what you are looking for https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html

Since you are in AWS, you could use S3 as storage for the remote states.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "prod_service1" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    region = "eu-west-1"
    bucket = "uservices_terraform_bucket_name"
    key    = "/states/prod/service1/terraform.tfstate"

    access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
    secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
    token      = "${var.aws_session_token}"
  }
}
```

Then you would be able to use the outputs of the terraform states in another microservice using

```
"${data.terraform_remote_state.prod_service1.api_id}"
```